# Как зашифровать пароль в базу данных H2 через BCrypt?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, h2

Я использую базу данныз H2, проект на Spring Boot 2 со следующим конфигом:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/activate/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Есть файл data.sql, делающий insert при старте:

```
insert into users (email, username, password)
values ('admin@gmail.com', 'admin', 'admin'),
       ('user@gmail.com', 'user', 'password'),
       ('user2@gmail.com', 'user2', 'password');

insert into user_role (user_id, roles)
values (100000, 'ADMIN'),
       (100000, 'USER'),
       (100001, 'USER'),
       (100002, 'USER');
```

На текущий момент при попытке авторизации через этих пользователей я получаю ошибку - `Encoded password does not look like BCrypt`

Мне нужно либо зашифровать эти пароли через BCrypt, либо целиком переписать схему шифрования. Подскажите - как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас 2 пути.

1. Зашифровать пароли самостоятельно и в `data.sql` прописать их в зашифрованном виде. Для этого надо через `PasswordEncoder` действовать. Пример: `passwordEncoder.encode(target)`
2. Записывать в БД пароли программно через Spring - тогда они сами зашифруются.